# Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have taken a copy of an OpenCart installation (version 2.0.3.1) and put on to  Windows localhost.

I've fixed a couple of the issues, but I've now come up against an error that I can't resolve:

*Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in ..\index.php on line 31*

I've searched Google, but no-one else seems to have come across the same problem.

Can someone tell me where this class resides?

The relevant lines in the index.php file are:

```
   CODE: 

   23    // Registry
   24    $registry = new Registry();
   25    
   26    // Loader
   27    $loader = new Loader($registry);
   28    $registry->set('load', $loader);
   29    
   30    // Config
   31    $config = new Config(); // HERE
   32    $registry->set('config', $config);
```

Answer (score 5):

I got this error - but it was due to me adding config.php to my .gitignore file.

I only wanted to ignore my settings files but this caused the config.php class file to also be ignored from the **/system/library** folder (same name!)

just make sure that config.php exists in the library folder - but make sure it contains **config class** - not your oc settings!

Comment: omg! Thank you.. searching for about an hour for this

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while integrating it on the local machine. Follow these steps, it might help:-

1. Download the opencart package of version 2.0.3.1 from the website or download from this link: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download/success&download_id=41
2. Open the downloaded folder and navigate to System/library folder.
3. Copy config.php file from there and paste in your project location in the same folder System/library.
4. It will ask to replace the file, do that and it should solve the problem.

Also, make sure you have written something like this on top of index file or not **require_once('config.php');**

I hope this helps.

Comment: Even after replacing the config file you are getting same error?